# iPhone SDK: UIActionsheet Delegate Method not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiactionsheet

In my iPhone app, I have an actionsheet which has 4 buttons.

Now to perform actions on click of these buttons, I have implemented ActionSheet Delegate.

The action sheet delegate method does not get called on click of the buttons. The same code works when integrated to another project.

I have declared all the method names properly.

Below is the screenshot which shows the delegate method

[image]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Post your code directly rather than showing its image

Comment: Did you set `[actionSheet setDelegate:self]` or You didn't forget to set *delegate* to *self* when you create the actionSheet?

Comment: The issue will be in how you create and/or display the action sheet, not in the delegate method.

Comment: Simon: I have marked my answer. Please Checkout CMLlyod's Answer.

Comment: You probably don't want to post your appid on a public forum...

Comment: ok fine thanks Harkonian. I was not aware about it. I have removed that. Thanks :)

Comment: The appid in this question is still visible in the question history. I hope that has been invalidated at the Apple end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have set your UIActionSheet delegate to self:

```
actionSheet.delegate = self;
```

and also make sure you're implementing `<UIActionSheetDelegate>` in the header file.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the code to call the action sheet like below

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"YOUR TITLE" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"YOUR MESSAGE" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet release];
```

Then there won't be an issue calling the delegate method,

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Cheers